# One-liner to change multiple strings, upcase, downcase etc?

Tags: ruby, string, variables

Hey first day coding ruby and I'm wondering if there is any method to changing multiple variables in one line for instance.

```
first_name = "JOHN"
last_name = "DOE"
[first_name, last_name] = [first_name, last_name].downcase

Output : john doe
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't say what language(s) you are coming from, but Ruby's `map` and `collect` are a common functionality in many languages. Perl, which I came from, uses its own flavor of `map`, which is syntactically different, but accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the values, use [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
first_name = "JOHN"
last_name = "DOE"
first_name, last_name = [first_name, last_name].map &:downcase

p first_name # => john
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to use the `!` version of the `downcase` method

```
[first_name, last_name].each {|str| str.downcase!}
```

which can also be written :

```
[first_name, last_name].each(&:downcase!)
```

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer, *as long* as the OP understands the implications of modifying strings "in place". Otherwise, he will get bitten by aliasing bugs at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "collect".

```
[first_name, last_name].collect(&:downcase)
```

which returns

```
=> ["john", "doe"]
```

and if you want to join them together as a full name, you can use "join".

```
[first_name, last_name].collect(&:downcase).join(' ')
```

which returns

```
=> "john doe"
```